# GitLab: how to reliably pass gitlab-runner-defined environment variables to a child pipeline?

Tags: gitlab, environment-variables, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a gitlab-runner that contains the following in its `config.toml`:

```
[[runners]]
  executor = "docker"
  ...
  environment = ["MY_VARIABLE=1.2.3.4"]
```

I have a pipeline with a `env | sort` shell command so that I can inspect the variables. I can see that this variable appears in the job's environment correctly.

This pipeline spawns a child pipeline with:

```
child-pipeline:
  trigger:
    include: child.gitlab-ci.yml
    strategy: depend
  variables:
    PARENT_PIPELINE_ID: $CI_PIPELINE_ID
```

Note: the assignment of `PARENT_PIPELINE_ID` to `$CI_PIPELINE_ID` is to allow the child pipeline to reference jobs in the parent pipeline via `needs` rules.

I also have a `env | sort` in my child pipeline, for environment inspection. I see that my variable `MY_VARIABLE` is present, with the value set in the runner's config.

So far so good.

The problem occurs when I want to override this variable from the "Pipelines" page, where I can click "Run pipeline" and specify an overriding value for my variable:

[image: screenshot]

If I do this, then my main (parent) pipeline shows this variable with the new value, as expected, but the child pipeline sees the original value as set in the runner's `config.toml`.

So I tried this, to pass the variable to the child pipeline explicitly:

```
child-pipeline:
  trigger:
    include: child.gitlab-ci.yml
    strategy: depend
  variables:
    PARENT_PIPELINE_ID: $CI_PIPELINE_ID
    MY_VARIABLE: $MY_VARIABLE
```

And if I manually set a value in Run Pipeline, this works - both the parent and child pipelines have the correct value of `MY_VARIABLE`.

But there's a problem! If I don't override this variable in the Run Pipeline window, perhaps I just let the pipeline run normally, or auto-triggered on a commit, then the child pipeline doesn't get the `config.toml` value at all, in fact it gets the value as literally `$MY_VARIABLE`! I.e. the value is the actual string `"$MY_VARIABLE"`.

Environment variables confuse me in GitLab. Some variables aren't visible all the time - for example, gitlab-runner variables aren't "seen" when parsing the .gitlab-ci.yml, only when running it. I'm sure this issue I have has something to do with mixing GitLab runner variables with Pipeline variables, but it's not making any sense to me. Note that I'm *not* using variables hand-set in `Settings > CI/CD > Variables` because I want the value of `MY_VARIABLE` to be set *by the runner*, since I actually have multiple runners and the value varies between them.

Do you know how to handle this situation properly?

Comment: Well, since GitLab can't determine what runner will run a job ahead of time, there's no way to know what variables are configured on the runner. Luckily runner variables are fairly low precedence.  The important thing is to be familiar is the [variable precedence](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#cicd-variable-precedence) in GitLab CI. Is there a reason you need these variables on your runner and not somewhere else?

Comment: @sytech the runners are on different hosts and have physical hardware attached, so the idea was that the runner could define these host-specific variables, and the jobs would use whatever values they were set to. I did find a temporary workaround by using the Project variables, but it loses the runner-host-specific feature.

Comment: Perhaps there's another way to propagate variables to a child pipeline that doesn't require reference to them in the gitlab YAML syntax? Perhaps via an env file. Investigating...

Comment: Maybe consider just mounting a read-only file into all jobs using the runner's `volume` configuration (if using a docker-based executor) -- similarly for shell runner... you could just have a RO file on the filesystem somewhere. Then your job can read the file. In other words, you'd read the file and set variables via `export` rather than relying on GitLab to provide the variables. Would that work? Or does the child YAML need the variables?

Comment: I think this would work in almost all cases, except the `resource_group` case I happen to have around a child pipeline - in this case the variable needs to be in the YAML. However I could do this with a Dynamic Pipeline, generating the YAML on the fly. Combined with your idea, that might just work. I will think more about it. Thank you.